# PHPStorm: File Watchers de SCSS a CSS => generando a una estructura de directorios diferente

Tags: php, ide

Tengo una estructura de directorios con archivos SCSS así:

- component => folder1 => scss => file1.scss
- component => folder2 => scss => file2.scss

Me gustaría generar los CSS correspondientes en la estructura de directorios siguientes:

- media => folder1 => css => file1.css
- media => folder2 => css => file2.css

Creo que debo usar MACROS para ello pero no sé cómo ya que la estructura es diferente (necesitaría tener en macro el "folder1" o "folder2".

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con ello?

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Mike

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, te recomiendo que cambies de idioma tu pregunta si no quieres que sea cerrada.

Comment: Deberias de traducir tu pregunta al Español para que no sea cerrada.

Comment: Gracias. La pondré en Español.